# On imageclick open the image in another activity

Tags: android

I have an imageView in which image is loaded from a url. On image click i want to display the image in another activity which contain a custom view. I am getting error and the acitvity crashes when I click on the image.

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    ImageLoader imgLoader;
    String strURL = "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/cats-250-250.jpg";
   // URI uri = null;
   // URL url = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(strURL, imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MemeCreateActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(MemeCreateActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH, strURL);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


}
}
```

MemeCreateActivity

```
public class MemeCreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MemeSetting.OnMemeSettingChangedListener<Typeface, Bitmap>,
        BottomSheetLayout.OnSheetStateChangeListener, OnSheetDismissedListener {
    //########################
    //## Static
    //########################
    public final static int RESULT_MEME_EDITING_FINISHED = 150;
    public final static int RESULT_MEME_EDIT_SAVED = 1;
    public final static int RESULT_MEME_NOT_SAVED = 0;
    public final static String EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH = "extraImage";
    public final static String ASSET_IMAGE = "assetImage";


    //########################
    //## UI Binding
    //########################
    @BindView(R.id.fab)
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @BindView(R.id.memecreate__activity__bottomsheet_layout)
    BottomSheetLayout bottomSheet;

    @BindView(R.id.memecreate__activity__image)
    ImageView imageEditView;

    @BindView(R.id.memecreate__activity__edit_caption_bottom)
    EditText textEditBottomCaption;

    @BindView(R.id.memecreate__activity__edit_caption_top)
    EditText textEditTopCaption;

    //#####################
    //## Members
    //#####################
    private static boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    private Bitmap lastBitmap = null;
    private long memeSavetime = -1;
    private App app;
    private MemeSetting<Typeface, Bitmap> memeSetting;
    private boolean bFullscreenImage = true;

    //#####################
    //## Methods
    //#####################
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memecreate__activity);

        // Quit activity if no image was given
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")) &&
                (!getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH) || !getIntent().hasExtra(ASSET_IMAGE))) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Bind Ui
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        app = (App) getApplication();

        // Set toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }


        Bitmap bitmap = extractBitmapFromIntent(intent);
        memeSetting = new MemeSetting<>(app.getFonts().get(app.settings.getLastSelectedFont()), bitmap);
        memeSetting.setDisplayImage(memeSetting.getImage().copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false));
        memeSetting.setFontId(app.settings.getLastSelectedFont());

        textEditTopCaption.setText(memeSetting.getCaptionTop());
        textEditBottomCaption.setText(memeSetting.getCaptionBottom());

        memeSetting.setMemeSettingChangedListener(this);
        memeSetting.notifyChangedListener();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        imageEditView.setImageBitmap(null);
        if (lastBitmap != null && !lastBitmap.isRecycled())
            lastBitmap.recycle();
        if (!memeSetting.getImage().isRecycled())
            memeSetting.getImage().recycle();
        if (!memeSetting.getDisplayImage().isRecycled())
            memeSetting.getDisplayImage().recycle();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (bFullscreenImage) {
            bFullscreenImage = false;
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap extractBitmapFromIntent(final Intent intent) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH);
        App.log("imagepath::" + imagePath);
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && intent.getType().startsWith("image/")) {
            Uri imageURI = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (imageURI != null) {
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageURI);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    bitmap = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ASSET_IMAGE, false)) {
            try {
                //Scale big images down to avoid "out of memory"
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(imagePath);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0), options);
                options.inSampleSize = Helpers.calculateInSampleSize(options, app.settings.getRenderQuality());
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = getAssets().open(imagePath);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0), options);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                bitmap = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //Scale big images down to avoid "out of memory"
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
            options.inSampleSize = Helpers.calculateInSampleSize(options, app.settings.getRenderQuality());
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (bottomSheet.isSheetShowing()) {
            bottomSheet.dismissSheet();
            return;
        }
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.creator__press_back_again_to_exit, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.memecreate__activity__image)
    public void onImageClicked(View view) {
        Helpers.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.creatememe__menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_share: {
                app.shareBitmapToOtherApp(lastBitmap, this);
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.action_save: {
                saveMemeToFilesystem();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void saveMemeToFilesystem() {
        String filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.app_name)).getAbsolutePath();
        String thumbnailPath = new File(filepath, getString(R.string.dot_thumbnails)).getAbsolutePath();
        if (memeSavetime < 0) {
            memeSavetime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        String filename = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s_%d.jpg", getString(R.string.app_name), memeSavetime);
        if (Helpers.saveBitmapToFile(filepath, filename, lastBitmap) != null && Helpers.saveBitmapToFile(thumbnailPath, filename, Helpers.createThumbnail(lastBitmap)) != null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.creator__saved_successfully)
                    .setMessage(R.string.creator__saved_successfully_message)
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab)
    public void onFloatingButtonClicked(View view) {
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bottomSheet.showWithSheetView(((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
                inflate(R.layout.memecreate__bottom_sheet, bottomSheet, false));
        bottomSheet.addOnSheetStateChangeListener(this);
        bottomSheet.addOnSheetDismissedListener(this);

        LineColorPicker colorPickerShade = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__color_picker_for_border);
        LineColorPicker colorPickerText = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__color_picker_for_text);
        Spinner dropdownFont = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__dropdown_font);
        SeekBar seekFontSize = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__seek_font_size);
        ToggleButton toggleAllCaps = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__toggle_all_caps);

        colorPickerText.setColors(MemeLibConfig.MEME_COLORS.ALL);
        colorPickerShade.setColors(MemeLibConfig.MEME_COLORS.ALL);

        FontAdapter adapter = new FontAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, app.getFonts());
        dropdownFont.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Apply existing settings
        colorPickerText.setSelectedColor(memeSetting.getTextColor());
        colorPickerShade.setSelectedColor(memeSetting.getBorderColor());
        dropdownFont.setSelection(memeSetting.getFontId());
        toggleAllCaps.setChecked(memeSetting.isAllCaps());
        ((SeekBar) ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.memecreate__bottom_sheet__seek_font_size)).setProgress(memeSetting.getFontSize() - MemeLibConfig.FONT_SIZES.MIN);

        //
        //  Add bottom sheet listeners
        //
        colorPickerShade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LineColorPicker picker = (LineColorPicker) v;
                memeSetting.setBorderColor(picker.getColor());
            }
        });
        colorPickerText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LineColorPicker picker = (LineColorPicker) v;
                memeSetting.setTextColor(picker.getColor());
            }
        });
        dropdownFont.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                memeSetting.setFont((MemeFont<Typeface>) parent.getSelectedItem());
                memeSetting.setFontId(parent.getSelectedItemPosition());
                app.settings.setLastSelectedFont(memeSetting.getFontId());
            }
        });
        seekFontSize.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                memeSetting.setFontSize(progress + MemeLibConfig.FONT_SIZES.MIN);
            }
        });
        toggleAllCaps.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                memeSetting.setAllCaps(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    public Bitmap drawMultilineTextToBitmap(Context c, MemeSetting<Typeface, Bitmap> memeSetting) {
        // prepare canvas
        Resources resources = c.getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = memeSetting.getDisplayImage();

        float scale = Helpers.getScalingFactor(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        float borderScale = scale * memeSetting.getFontSize() / MemeLibConfig.FONT_SIZES.DEFAULT;
        Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        }
        // resource bitmaps are immutable,
        // so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // new antialiased Paint
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setTextSize((int) (memeSetting.getFontSize() * scale));
        paint.setTypeface(memeSetting.getFont().getFont());
        //paint.setStrokeWidth(memeSetting.getFontSize() / 4);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(borderScale);

        String[] textStrings = {memeSetting.getCaptionTop(), memeSetting.getCaptionBottom()};
        if (memeSetting.isAllCaps()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < textStrings.length; i++) {
                textStrings[i] = textStrings[i].toUpperCase();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < textStrings.length; i++) {
            paint.setColor(memeSetting.getBorderColor());
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

            // set text width to canvas width minus 16dp padding
            int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);

            // init StaticLayout for text
            StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(
                    textStrings[i], paint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            // get height of multiline text
            int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

            // get position of text's top left corner  center: (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth)/2
            float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
            float y = 0;
            if (i == 0)
                y = bitmap.getHeight() / 15;
            else
                y = bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight;

            // draw text to the Canvas center
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(x, y);
            textLayout.draw(canvas);

            // new antialiased Paint
            paint.setColor(memeSetting.getTextColor());
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            // init StaticLayout for text
            textLayout = new StaticLayout(
                    textStrings[i], paint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            // get height of multiline text
            textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

            // draw text to the Canvas center
            textLayout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @OnTextChanged(value = R.id.memecreate__activity__edit_caption_bottom, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.TEXT_CHANGED)
    public void onCaptionBottomChanged(CharSequence text) {
        memeSetting.setCaptionBottom(text.toString());
    }

    @OnTextChanged(value = R.id.memecreate__activity__edit_caption_top, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.TEXT_CHANGED)
    public void onCaptionTopChanged(CharSequence text) {
        memeSetting.setCaptionTop(text.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMemeSettingChanged(MemeSetting<Typeface, Bitmap> memeSetting) {
        imageEditView.setImageBitmap(null);
        if (lastBitmap != null)
            lastBitmap.recycle();
        Bitmap bmp = drawMultilineTextToBitmap(this, memeSetting);
        imageEditView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        lastBitmap = bmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSheetStateChanged(BottomSheetLayout.State state) {
        if (state == BottomSheetLayout.State.HIDDEN) {
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textEditBottomCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textEditTopCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (state == BottomSheetLayout.State.EXPANDED || state == BottomSheetLayout.State.PEEKED) {
            textEditBottomCaption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textEditTopCaption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(BottomSheetLayout bottomSheetLayout) {
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in the logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: io.github.gsantner.memetastic, PID: 18271
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {io.github.gsantner.memetastic/io.github.gsantner.memetastic.activity.MemeCreateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3497)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3515)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at io.github.gsantner.memetastic.activity.MemeCreateActivity.onDestroy(MemeCreateActivity.java:150)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5403)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3515) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the `memecreate__activity.xml` layout

Comment: "io.github.gsantner.memetastic.activity.MemeCreateActivity.onDestroy(MemeCreateActivity.java:150)" Did you place a breakpoint there?

Comment: @efekctive I am not aware what a breakpoint actually and how can I implement it

Comment: It is a feature inside most IDE, It is what tells debuggers where to stop execution and allow the developer control execution. The stack trace has this line as the root cause of the NPE

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call getIntent two times but actually it should receive intent only once

So, in your second activity method onCreate, remove these lines

```
if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")) && (!getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH) || !getIntent().hasExtra(ASSET_IMAGE))) { finish(); return; }
```

And add these lines instead

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")) && (!i.hasExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH) || !i.hasExtra(ASSET_IMAGE))) { finish(); return; }
```

Answer (score 0):

move your Butterknife binding to the top of `oncreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.memecreate__activity);

    // Bind Ui
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // Quit activity if no image was given
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")) &&
            (!getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH) || !getIntent().hasExtra(ASSET_IMAGE))) {
        finish();
        return;
    }


    app = (App) getApplication();
```